# I don't know what am I doing. Python 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'close' error

Tags: python

I have this code for a pronunciation scoring assistant:

```
import speech_recognition as sr

def evaluate_pronunciation(phrase):
    recognizer = sr.Recognizer()
    microphone = sr.Microphone()
    
    with microphone as source:
        recognizer.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source)
        audio = recognizer.listen(source)
    
    try:
        spoken_text = recognizer.recognize_google(audio)
        print(f"You said: {spoken_text}")
        
        if phrase.lower() == spoken_text.lower():
            score = 1.0
            suggestion = ""
        else:
            score = 0.0
            suggestion = f"You said '{spoken_text}', but the correct phrase is '{phrase}'."
        
        return score, suggestion
    
    except sr.UnknownValueError:
        suggestion = "Sorry, we could not understand what you said. Please try again."
        score = 0.0
        return score, suggestion

# Example usage
phrase = "hello world"
score, suggestion = evaluate_pronunciation(phrase)
print(f"Your score is {score}")
print(suggestion)
```

But I am encountering an error that says: "'NoneType' object has no attribute 'close'."

What is wrong with the code? What does the error mean, and how can I fix the problem?

Comment: typically you would share the full copied error message, with traceback, verbatim

Comment: try installing - `pip install pyaudio`. as it is one of the dependencies for `speech_recognition`. you are getting the audio as `None`.

Comment: Nowhere in the code (as shown) do you [try to] call *close()* on any object

Comment: @DarkKnight.  I suspect it is implicit in the `with microphone as source`.